# Видео с сайта на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! Как сделать, чтобы видео с сайта своего воспроизводилось на телефонах, на ipad и так далее? спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Использовать [html5 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Video)

To [[@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek)](/users/4597/shrek) [тыц](http://www.macguide.ru/flash-on-ipad/)

**upd** - 
По поводу youtube полезно почитать [здесь](http://www.youtube.com/html5?hl=ru)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, загрузите на ютуб и выложите у себя на сайте блок от ютуба.